# How to print names of all menuitems in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, toolstripdropdown

I am new to programming. I need to get a list of ALL menuItems (ToolStripMenuItems) including Dropdown menuitems. I found some codes, but it list Main Menu Items only, No Dropdown menuItems. Can you give me a suitable code for list ALL menuItems.

```
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip.Items)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(item.Name);
    }
```

Comment: " ... or Madam" there might be some female fellows too ;)

Answer (score 3):

The child items have a [`DropDownItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownitem.dropdownitems.aspx) collection.

Write a recursive function like this one:

```
private void print( ToolStripMenuItem element )
{
    MessageBox.Show(element.Name);

    foreach ( ToolStripMenuItem child in element.DropDownItems )
    { 
        print( child );
    }
}
```

Comment: May be print( child ); instead of print( element );